# Get rid of duplicate rows in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

First of all, this is a database I was given, and it is a pain to work with.

I have this table:

| content_id | version | content_version_id | alias | publish_date | contentattribute_name | contentattribute_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4507 | 4 | 10369 | /aktuelt/arkiv/ | 04/04/2014 | category_names | CAT1, CAT2 |
| 4348 | 3 | 10373 | /publikasjoner/ | 23/05/2011 | category_names | CAT1, CAT2 |
| 4348 | 4 | 10374 | /publikasjoner/ | 23/05/2011 | category_names | CAT1, CAT2 |
| 4439 | 3 | 10701 | /publikasjoner/ | 08/04/2015 | category_names | CAT1, CAT2 |
| 4439 | 4 | 10702 | /publikasjoner/ | 08/04/2015 | category_names | CAT1, CAT2 |

I am trying to get rid of duplicates from the column "content_id", and I've searched for answers on stackoverflow, but I couldn't get it to work with my SQL query.

Can anyone help me with the current query?

```
SELECT db_name.contentversion.ContentId as 'content_id',
db_name.contentversion.Version as 'version',
db_name.contentversion.ContentVersionId as 'content_version_id', 
db_name.content.alias as 'alias',
db_name.content.PublishDate as 'publish_date', 
db_name.contentattributes.Name as 'contentattribute_name', 
db_name.contentattributes.Value as 'contentattribute_value'
FROM db_name.contentversion
JOIN db_name.content
ON db_name.content.ContentId = db_name.contentversion.ContentId
JOIN db_name.contentattributes
ON db_name.contentattributes.ContentVersionId = db_name.contentversion.ContentVersionId
```

EDIT

I think I managed to solve it by using this query:

```
SELECT cv.ContentId, cv.Version, cv.ContentVersionId,
db_name.content.alias AS "alias",
db_name.content.PublishDate AS "publish_date", 
db_name.contentattributes.Name AS "contentattribute_name", 
db_name.contentattributes.Value AS "contentattribute_value"
FROM contentversion cv
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ContentId, MAX(Version) Version
    FROM contentversion
    GROUP BY ContentId
) b ON cv.ContentId = b.ContentId AND cv.Version = b.Version
JOIN db_name.content
ON db_name.content.ContentId = cv.ContentId
JOIN db_name.contentattributes
ON db_name.contentattributes.ContentVersionId = cv.ContentVersionId
```

Comment: When only selecting one version of `content_id` you need to use [distinct](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) - consider, that distinct does not consider any sorting. But if you have special requirements to how to filter `content_id` please provide your specifications.

Comment: The mistake was that you were thinking in duplicates, while it wasn't duplicates you had to deal with. `DISTINCT` removes duplicate rows from a data set. You don't need it. You can remove it from your  final query. What you want instead is the top row (the one with the greatest version) per group (content ID). Your final version shows one appoach to solve this. You can write it as an answer and accept it yourself, so everyone sees that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: On a side  note: Don't use single quotes for names. Single quotes are for string literals. If you `ORDER BY 'alias'` you order by a string constant, i.e. you don't sort anything at all. Use double quotes for this instead (`AS "alias"`). MySQL also allows backticks for names (`AS \`alias\``). In your case you don't need any quotes at all (`AS alias`), because there are no problematic characters in the names (such as blanks for instance). And this is the best thing you can do anyway, just avoid special characters and you don't have to quote the names.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer and the tip about single quotes, I didn't know :) I'll update with the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final query that worked for me was (thanks to Thorsten Kettner):

```
SELECT cv.ContentId, cv.Version, cv.ContentVersionId,
db_name.content.alias AS "alias",
db_name.content.PublishDate AS "publish_date", 
db_name.contentattributes.Name AS "contentattribute_name", 
db_name.contentattributes.Value AS "contentattribute_value"
FROM contentversion cv
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ContentId, MAX(Version) Version
    FROM contentversion
    GROUP BY ContentId
) b ON cv.ContentId = b.ContentId AND cv.Version = b.Version
JOIN db_name.content
ON db_name.content.ContentId = cv.ContentId
JOIN db_name.contentattributes
ON db_name.contentattributes.ContentVersionId = cv.ContentVersionId
```

Comment: You are still using single quotes where you shouln't use them. The query would be more readable, did you indent some rows. Alias names are made to enhance a query's readability. Names like a and b, though, don't help with readabilty at all. Use something mnemonic like cv for contentversion. At last you may want to write AS in upper case to stay consistent in your upper / lower case convention, as AS is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like content_id is not a primary key and it can hold in two different versions ie 3 or 4. You may want to get the version you are interested in so that you filter it using `WHERE version= ?` or just take `distinct content_id` if the version type doesn't matter

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but using DISTINCT didnt work, and to filter version is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: What's your primary key in that table

Answer (score 0):

You have to omit **version** and **content_version_id** columns from the query as it has different values for the same **content_id**. Then, remove duplicate using group by clause as following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT db_name.contentversion.ContentId as content_id,
 db_name.content.alias as alias,
 db_name.content.PublishDate as publish_date, 
 db_name.contentattributes.Name as contentattribute_name, 
 db_name.contentattributes.Value as contentattribute_value
FROM db_name.contentversion
JOIN db_name.content
ON db_name.content.ContentId = db_name.contentversion.ContentId;
```

Comment: Thank you, but omitting those columns is not an option as I need to get the values "relis.contentattributes.Name" and "relis.contentattributes.Value".

Comment: And we don't use `GROUP BY` without any aggregation function involved usually. `DISTINCT` does the same, is easier to read and write, and makes it obvious what the intention is.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yeah I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

You want the maximum version per content ID. Probably the best approach for this is a lateral join, available since MySQL 8.0.14.

```
SELECT 
  cv.contentid, 
  cv.version, 
  cv.contentversionid,
  c.alias,
  c.publishdate AS publish_date, 
  ca.name AS contentattribute_name,
  ca.value AS contentattribute_value
FROM db_name.content c
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
(
  SELECT *
  FROM contentversion
  WHERE contentversion.contentid = c.contentid
  ORDER BY contentversion.version DESC
  LIMIT 1
) cv
INNER JOIN db_name.contentattributes ca ON ca.contentversionid = cv.contentversionid
ORDER BY cv.contentid, ca.name;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The database version I am working with is 5.7.31, so I can't verify your query. Probably something I should've mentioned in the post.

Comment: Don't worry, my answer can still help others :-) I am sorry that you must work an old version. MySQL made a huge leap in my opinion when they issued version 8 some years ago.